# Twitter search api blocked from Amazon EC2 in Ruby only, not curl...is this Net::HTTP?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, twitter, amazon-ec2

This is a weird one that anyone can repro at home (I think) - I am trying to write a simple service to run searches on Twitter on a service hosted on EC2. Twitter returns me errors 100% of the time when run in ruby, but not in other languages, which would indicate it's not an IP-blocking issue. Here is an example:

```
admin@ec2-xx-101-152-xxx-production:~$ irb
irb(main):001:0> require 'net/http'
=> true
irb(main):002:0> res = Net::HTTP.post_form(URI.parse('http://search.twitter.com/search.json'), {'q' => 'twitter'})
=> #<Net::HTTPBadRequest 400 Bad Request readbody=true>
irb(main):003:0> exit
admin@ec2-xx-101-152-xxx-production:~$ curl http://search.twitter.com/search.json?q=twitter
{"results":[{"text":"&quot;Social Media and SE(Search Engine) come side by side to help promote your business and bran...<snip/>
```

As you see, CURL works, irb does not. When I run on my local windows box in irb, success:

```
$ irb
irb(main):001:0> require 'net/http'
=> true
irb(main):002:0> res = Net::HTTP.post_form(URI.parse('http://search.twitter.com/search.json'), {'q' => 'twitter'})
=> #<Net::HTTPOK 200 OK readbody=true>
```

This is confusing...if there was some kind of core bug in Net::HTTP, I would think it would show up both on windows and linux, and if I was being blocked by my IP, then curl shouldn't work either. I tried this on a fresh Amazon instance too with a fresh IP addy.

Anyone should be able to repro this 'cause I'm using the ec2onrails ami:

```
ec2-run-instances ami-5394733a -k testkeypair
```

Just ssh in after that and run those simple lines above. Anyone have ideas what's going on?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Check the Twitter API changelog. They are blocking requests from EC2 that don't have a User-Agent header in the HTTP request because people are using EC2 to find terms to spam.

Twitter recommends setting the User-Agent to your domain name, so they can check out sites that are causing problems and get in touch with you.

Comment: Where can one find the changelog? I am facing this same problem with the tweetstream gem. I set the user_agent to my domain name, but it is still unauthorized. The exact same credentials when run from my laptop (which has a different IP) works.

Answer (score 0):

The HTTP 400 error message is returned by twitter when a single client exceeds the number of maximum requests per hour. I don't know how your ec2 instance is configured therefore I don't know if your request is identified by a shared Amazon IP or a custom IP. In the first case it's reasonable to think that the limit is reached in a very small amount of time.

More details are available in the Twitter API doumentation:

- [error codes](http://apiwiki.twitter.com/HTTP-Response-Codes-and-Errors)
- [rate limiting](http://apiwiki.twitter.com/Rate-limiting)

To have more details about the reason of the error response, read your response content or headers. You should find an error message and some X-RateLimit twitter headers.

```
require 'net/http'
response = Net::HTTP.post_form(URI.parse('http://search.twitter.com/search.json'), {'q' => 'twitter'})

p response.headers
p response.body
```

Comment: Right, this was the first thing I considered, but if I was hitting the max, then the curl request sent immediately afterward should also report a failure. 

I am using an instance associated with a static IP, and I checked and requests are indeed coming from from allocated static IP. The response body adds little information: 

"<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC \"-//IETF//DTD HTML 2.0//EN\">\n<html><head>\n<title>400 Bad Request</title>\n</head><body>\n<h1>Bad Request</h1>\n<p>Your browser sent a request that this server could not understand.<br />\n</p>\n</body></html>"

Comment: And php also fails with a 400 error. It would make sense if this was a simple blocked IP issue, but the fact remains that curl from the command line works...I'm wondering if curl is adding some header (a user-agent perhaps??) that twitter likes to see...I'm about to just write code to manually call curl from my ruby script.

Comment: It is the blank user-agent string. It had nothing to do with request limits being hit. I solved this issue in one line in ruby: 

    Twitter::Search.default_options = {:headers => {'User-Agent' =>
        'YOUR_USER_AGENT_STRING'}}

I also filed an issue with jnunemaker's twitter gem on github

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the info.  Putting my domain in the USER-AGENT header fixed the same problem for me.  I'm running http://LocalChirps.com on EC2 servers.

CURL Code snippet (PHP):

```
$twitter_api_url = 'http://search.twitter.com/search.atom?rpp='.$count.'&page='.$page;
$ch = curl_init($twitter_api_url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, 'LocalChirps.com');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
$twitter_data = curl_exec($ch);
$httpcode = curl_getinfo($ch, CURLINFO_HTTP_CODE);
curl_close($ch);
if ($httpcode != 200) {
    //echo 'error calling twitter';
    return;
}
```